# Excel VLOOKUP for range of dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, vlookup

I have been struggling with `VLOOKUP` for sometime. I want to use `VLOOKUP` for a range of dates using the two tables I have given. I want to get which Term each row belongs to. Basically I want to check if

**OppCreatedDate**>=**startDate** and **CloseDate**<=**endDate** and get corresponding **marketingPeriod** from the lookup table

Table with dates:
[image: Table with dates]

Lookup table:
[image: Lookup table]

Comment: Can you use sumproduct? I.e. `=SUMPRODUCT ((A2:A20)*(B2:B20<=creatDate)*(C2:C20>=endDate))`

Comment: This SUMPRODUCT doesn't works even the ARRAY (CSE) formula,, returns #VALUE  error !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this array formula (entered using **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of regular Enter):

```
=INDEX(Lookup_table[marketingPeriod],MATCH(1,([@OppCreateDate]>=Lookup_table[startDate])*([@CloseDate]<=Lookup_table[endDate]),0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*An Array (CSE) formula solves the issue:*

**:Caveat:**

*For better understanding I've used small data range, you can use as many rows are required.*

- INDEX & MATCH is better & faster than VLOOKUP.
- Cell references,  without TABLE's & TABLE Column's name also works properly.

[image]

---

- An array (CSE) formula in cell X14:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX($AA$2:$AA$11, SMALL(IF(($X$2:$X$11>=$AB$2:$AB$11)+($Y$2:$Y$11<=$AC$2:$AC$11), MATCH(ROW($AA$2:$AA$11), ROW($AA$2:$AA$11)), ""), ROW(A1)), COLUMN(A1)),"")}
  ```

**N.B.**

- Finish formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.
- Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Your sample is incorrect, I changed the column CloseDate and use **LOOKUP** function:

```
=IFERROR(LOOKUP(1,0/(($F$1:$F$12<=A1)*($G$1:$G$12>=B1)),$E$1:$E$12),"")
```

[image]